# How do I set value to RedisSetting from code instead of config?

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I'm using Redis.StackExchange library and [CloudStructure](https://github.com/neuecc/CloudStructures) library

```
 public class RedisSettings
    {
        public RedisSettings(ConfigurationOptions configuration, int db = 0, IRedisValueConverter converter = null, Func<ICommandTracer> tracerFactory = null, TextWriter connectionMultiplexerLog = null);
      }
```

I want to set value for `IRedisValueConverter converter` from code instead of config.

How should I set it?

```
  public static readonly RedisSettings Default = new RedisSettings("localhost");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
public RedisSettings(ConfigurationOptions configuration, converter: YourConvertobject);
```

Converter is an optional argument and by default it is null. By providing a value you can set it from code. For more information read [Named & Optional parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)

Comment: I have a separate class for my convertor like `JsonConvertor.cs` i'm bit new in this so , how can I set this as my converter?

Comment: When you're initialising RedisSetting, provide the converter there. I am not on my windows PC right now so i will update with a working code in a couple of hours